# having trouble creating ken burns effect with CALayer for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, avfoundation, calayer

I have been trying for the last few days to create the ken burns effect using a CALayer with animations and then save it to a video file.

I have my image layer which is inside another layer that is 1024x576. All of the animations are applied to the image layer.

Here is the code so far:

```
- (CALayer*)buildKenBurnsLayerWithImage:(UIImage *)image startPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint fromScale:(float)fromScale toScale:(float)toScale
{
    float calFromScale = fromScale + 1;
    float calToScale = toScale + 1;
    float fromX = startPoint.x * calFromScale;
    float fromY = (image.size.height * calFromScale) - (videoSize.height + (startPoint.y * calFromScale));
    float toX = endPoint.x * calToScale;
    float toY = (image.size.height * calToScale) - (videoSize.height + (endPoint.y * calToScale));

    CGPoint anchor = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);

    CALayer* imageLayer    = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.contents    = (id)image.CGImage;
    imageLayer.anchorPoint = anchor;
    imageLayer.bounds      = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    imageLayer.position    = CGPointMake(image.size.width * anchor.x, image.size.height * anchor.y);
    imageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;

    // create the panning animation.
    CABasicAnimation* panningAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    panningAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-fromX, -fromY)];
    panningAnimation.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-toX, -toY)];
    panningAnimation.additive = YES;
    panningAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    // create the scale animation.
    CABasicAnimation* scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fromScale];
    scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:toScale];
    scaleAnimation.additive = YES;
    scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    CAAnimationGroup* animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animationGroup.animations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:panningAnimation,scaleAnimation, nil];
    animationGroup.beginTime = 1e-100;
    animationGroup.duration = 5.0;
    animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animationGroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [imageLayer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:nil];

    return imageLayer;
}
```

Here is how i'm calling the method:

```
CALayer* animatedLayer = [self buildKenBurnsLayerWithImage:image startPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) endPoint:CGPointMake(500, 500) fromScale:5.0 toScale:2.0];
```

The problem I am having is that the end result with panning and scaling is off by a few pixels on the screen.

If someone knows how to fix this i would great appreciate it.

Comment: If you do not scale and just pan, does the problem still occur?

Answer (score 0):

All transformations are applied with respect to the anchor point. Try using the anchor point

```
CGPoint anchor = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
```

Your "viewport" should no longer scale to the bottom right (if that is responsible for the animation being off by a few pixels), but equally to all directions.